# Skipping levels of context binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am doing Knockout.js tutorial **(Tutorial: Single Page Applications, Step 2)** and I have problems to understand one thing. Maybe some code first:

View:

```
<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, 
                   css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
                   click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>

<!-- Mails grid -->
<table class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Subject</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: mails">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: from"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: to"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: subject"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

VieModel:

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
    self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { 
        self.chosenFolderId(folder);
        $.get('/mail', { folder: folder }, self.chosenFolderData);
    };

    // Show inbox by default
    self.goToFolder('Inbox'); };

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

Above snippets of code are working and list of emails is shown. Now my question is: how can I properly iterate over the mails when I get rid of **data-bind="with: chosenFolderData"** in table tag ? I tried to change **data-bind="foreach: mails"** into **data-bind="foreach: chosenFolderData().mails"** but it didn't work. That strange because I was able to get some data of first mail via:

**data-bind="text: chosenFolderData().mails[0].to"**

This is the ajax response:

```
Object {id: "Inbox", mails: Array[12]}
```

Anyone?

Comment: its looks like working for me if you are assigning data properly check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/27186/ . let us know your further concern

Comment: without `with` (which is preferable) as mentioned in OP it should work check here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/27187/

Comment: I think that it has something to do with asynchronous AJAX call. I see that in your example it does work but in my case I have still problems. Console shows error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return chosenFolderData().mails }"
Message: Cannot read property 'mails' of undefined

Comment: I tried another way: table class="mails" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData().mails" and foreach: $data" and it works. Very strange

Comment: 2nd case works because initially `mails` are undefined later when `mails` have data the view with data appears . To make it work  anyway use ajax promise methods i.e `.done` fill observableArray in it .

Comment: the above point should work for sure just in case stuck let us know . if it works let me know i can add it as answer .